# Using one line statement with looping in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i would like to know if is possible change this code below:

```
for key of index_of
 if file.text.indexOf(key) > -1
```

from to lines, to one line, like:

```
if file.text.indexOf(key) > -1 for key of index_of
```

I already try somethings but is not really working anyone..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, adding a `when` clause (which is only really documented in an example in [the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)) to your loop would probably be the easiest thing:

```
do_something_with_key for key of index_of when file.text.indexOf(key) > -1
```

That's the same as saying:

```
for key of index_of
    if(file.text.indexOf(key) > -1)
        do_something_with_key
```

If you need the `else` then you'd move the conditional logic into the loop body and add some parentheses to deal with precedence:

```
(if expr then ... else ...) for key of index_of
```

but that would be an unreadable mess so the long form would be better:

```
for key of index_of
    if expr
        ...
    else
        ...
```